# XCode 8 , Swift 2.3 returns error Could not build module

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, pubnub

After I updated to XCode 8 and we are trying to move to Swift 2.3 and I try to compile and build my project but there are few errors. I managed to get every other library working, only PubNub is unable to compile.

I Googled and try different solutions, nothing is working. I can build project from GitHub's test project

```
https://github.com/pubnub/SwiftExample
```

Errors are:

```
pleasurreApp/AppDelegate/AppDelegate.swift:14:8: Could not build Objective-C module 'PubNub'

Pods/PubNub/PubNub/Core/PubNub+CorePrivate.h:1:9: 'PubNub+Core.h' file not found
```

[image]

Comment: Try updating the Pod and then re-build.

Comment: I tried that, doesn't help

Comment: Which version are you using.

Comment: If you think of CocoaPods, it's the latest

Comment: facing same issue here ... Any luck ?

Comment: SOLUTION - problem was in XCode, I tried everything I could possibly think of to fix it. After installing new simulator inside XCode 8 it was fixed somehow and now it seems to be working. It's not the first time I had problems after new updating XCode to newest version. That's all I did, installed new simulator, went back home, turned on my Mac and it worked

Comment: @mihirmehta : I tried updating pods , restart mac, i installed  9.3 iPad simulator. Still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please run `pod update` from your project's root directory (or where `Podfile` is stored). Current **PubNub** SDK version is **4.5.3**.
Quit Xcode and delete **DerivedData** folder. After relaunch build should complete well.

Best regards,
Sergey

Comment: I'll try that and let you know

Comment: @FosAvance it looks like you used bridging header to add **PubNub** client to your application. How **PubNub** client added as framework bundle (if so, how it has been created and what version it is)? Swift support only dynamic frameworks (properly), so if CocoaPods has been used, there should be **use_frameworks** in _Podfile_.

Comment: I have that, it used to work before XCode 8 and iOS 10 update

Comment: SOLUTION - problem was in XCode, I tried everything I could possibly think of to fix it. After installing new simulator inside XCode 8 it was fixed somehow and now it seems to be working. It's not the first time I had problems after new updating XCode to newest version.

Comment: @FosAvance: I having exact same issue. How did you install new simulator inside xcode. can you please tell that.

Comment: I had to install iPhone iOS 8 simulator I think. But I think it was totally random thing that made it work.  I came home after installing simulator and somehow it worked. I even called PubNub's support, they told me everything is fine with library and PubNub and configuration. I think it was pure luck for me. It's problem in XCode, when I updated to newest version these days I had problem with my other projects and dependency libraries.